# Delete a document from firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building an app that contains pet adoption offers. Each pet document has an ID that's generated by DateTime.now() + the user ID to make it unique, anyway, I'm trying to write a deleting method within the Slidable widget to delete the adoption offer.
The problem is that I'm unable to reach the document ID to delete it.

Is there a way to delete a document without getting the ID?

This is the Firebase database
[image: Firebase database]

Here is my current code

```
Future getOffersList() async {
  List<PetTile> tiles = [];
  List<Slidable> slidables = [];
  var data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('pets')
      .where('owner',
          isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid.toString())
      .get();
  _petsList = List.from(data.docs.map((doc) => Pet.fromSnapshot(doc)));
  for (var pet in _petsList) {
    tiles.add(PetTile(pet: pet));
  }
  for (var tile in tiles) {
    slidables.add(
      Slidable(
        child: tile,
        endActionPane: ActionPane(
          motion: const DrawerMotion(),
          children: [
            SlidableAction(
              onPressed: (value) async {
                var ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('pets')
                    .where('id', isEqualTo: tile.pet.id)
                    .get();

                // Deleting...

              },
              backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFE4A49),
              foregroundColor: Colors.white,
              icon: Icons.delete,
              label: 'Delete',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: well i think you must get your id to delete it. check this link for more information https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#removing-data

Comment: You certainly are able to get an ID from the document.  It's in the snapshot of query results that you're working with.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the id of the document by doing the following steps:

1. Add await infront when you're accessing the conditioned data from firebase collection.. in your case in front of FirebaseFirestore.instance
   *This will return a QuerySnapshot rather than a Future instance of the same.
2. You need to get the doc and the id of that doc.. write:
   final id= ref.docs[0].id

*Using first index(0) because i am assuming that only one pet id matches with other pet id.

3. since you have the id now.. you can perform the delete function